# Run selenium scripts through GitHub #Jenkins

Tags: git, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying from last few days to integrate my selenium scripts which are located on GitHub repository with Jenkins but was unable to find anything useful/executable and nothing works for me so far. Does anyone has good steps to follow this scenario? I have built my scripts on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I acheive the following : 
* Selenium IDE HTML suites are stored on Bitbucket (which is a GIT) on a specific repository of my webapp project, let say **/WebContent/tests/htmlSuite.html**
* at the start and end of the build, I do run Selenium tests to ensure that building phase does not gives regressions.

This is acheive with selenium-server that is launched with command lines.
The plugin did not worked for me.

I do run a headless mode as I run my tests on EC2 Ubuntu so I had already installed VNCSERVER and configured it on display :6

I run the following script :

```
vncserver :6
export DISPLAY=:6

java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -acceptSslCerts -ensureCleanSession -htmlSuite "*chrome" "$URLStart" "$suiteTestFile" "$resultTestFile" -port 7856

vncserver -kill :6
```

where :

```
$URLStart = uri of tests
$suiteTestFile = location of your HTML suite
$resultTestFile = location of the result file
```

You can use HTML Publisher to then publish the report

Selenium tests did not work neither for me on firefox browser, this is why I use chrome.

Comment: Thanks @aorfevre but i didn't understand this!!i want to use to have automated test at a certain given time. there are some ways to do it by ant but nothing works for me.

Comment: what do you not undestand ? 
if you plan just to do Selenium tests, not building process for a web app, do a GIT reposiory with your testCase.

configure your GIT repo and configure it to force a clone 
Trigger the build with a cron task like : */5 * * * * for every 5 minutes for instance.

Please ask more questions if some stuff are not clear

Comment: how to create .HTML? i have .java scripts? so you mean to say don't use Jenkins, use git for that automated part?

Comment: I have never used .java Selenium as, for me, Selenium is great so non-developer can develop tests.
Therefore, I'm not able to provide more help... sry